# How can I send a string from fragment to class for changing the Json API in kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

when I click the button I want to change the link in the service but this is not working

how can ı send a string from fragment to class for changing the Json API ?

This is my interface

```
    interface NewsAPI {
    @GET
    fun getNews(@Url url:String):Single<API>
}
```

this is my service

```
class NewsAPIService {

    private val BASE_URL = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    private val api = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(NewsAPI::class.java)



    fun getData():Single<API>{
        return api.getNews(CountrySelectFragment().countrCode1)
    }
}
```

And this is my Fragment

```
class CountrySelectFragment : Fragment() {
 var countrCode1 = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_country_select, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    buttontr.setOnClickListener {
        countrCode1 = "trLink"
    }

    buttonar.setOnClickListener {
        countrCode1 = "arLink"

    }

    buttonuk.setOnClickListener {
        countrCode1 = "ukLink"
                }

    buttonus.setOnClickListener {
        countrCode1 = "usaLink"
    }
    buttonfr.setOnClickListener {
       countrCode1 = "frLink"
    }


}
```

}

What should I do for it ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried an OnClick function for all of the Button?
if not try this:

```
 override fun OnClick(view: View){

     when (view.id){ 
       R.id.buttontr-> return "trlink"
       R.id.button-> return "arlink"
       // the rest is the same
 }
}
```